# Windows Phone DoubleAnimation for Border

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I need to make some kind of property "EnableBlinking" for Border element which enables DoubleAnimation for Opacity with interval.

```
<Border CornerRadius="5" Background="Red" EnableBlinking="True" />
```

I found example with  but as far as I understand this is not supported in Windows Phone. And there is VisualStateManager. Can someone give me any example or good tutorial? I don't understand do I need to create Style, or new element.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for advaced XAML concept and can use Attached property with user control.

> Create User Control

```
<UserControl
    .................
         <UserControl.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Name="storyBoard">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="brd"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             From="0"
                             To="1"
                             RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                             AutoReverse="True"
                             Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                </Storyboard>

            </UserControl.Resources>
            <Grid>
                <Border  x:Name="brd" CornerRadius="5" Background="Red"/>
            </Grid>
        </UserControl>


public sealed partial class BorderControl : UserControl
    {
        public BorderControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static bool GetEnableBlinking(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(EnableBlinkingProperty);
        }

        public static void SetEnableBlinking(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(EnableBlinkingProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for EnableBlinking.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty EnableBlinkingProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("EnableBlinking", typeof(bool), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(0, (s, e) =>
            {
                (s as BorderControl).storyBoard.Begin();
            }));
    } 



 MainPage.xaml
<Grid>
        <local:BorderControl EnableBlinking="true" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Width="100"/>
    </Grid>
```

Here is Source Code: 
https://onedrive.live.com/?id=58D8C7A3527E52FB%21105&cid=58D8C7A3527E52FB

Comment: Thank you for your example. GetEnableBlinking and SetEnableBlinking. Is it equal to public bool EnableBlinking{get {return (bool)GetValue(EnableBlinkingProperty);} set{SetValue(EnableBlinkingProperty, (bool)value);} }? I use windows phone 8.0 platform

Comment: Most welcome David. This code is also working in Windows phone 8.0. Same concept and same code you can use in windows phone 8.0.